# Angular 4: unable to generate new components using Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to use the Angular CLI to generate a new component.

However, when I run `ng g component my-new-component` from my app root, I get the following error:

```
feilan@feilan-kubuntu:/media/feilan/Data/devprojects/web/udemy-angular4/components101$ ng g c moduleName --module='app.module.shared.ts'
The command "generate" has an option without the required type and name fields.
Error: The command "generate" has an option without the required type and name fields.
    at Class.validateOption (/media/feilan/Data/devprojects/web/udemy-angular4/components101/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:377:13)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Class.registerOptions (/media/feilan/Data/devprojects/web/udemy-angular4/components101/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:163:27)
    at getOptionsTask.run.then (/media/feilan/Data/devprojects/web/udemy-angular4/components101/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:98:18)
```

Alternatives  I have tried, without success:

- `ng generate`
- `ng generate --force`
- Running the command from `src/` and `src/app/`

Some version info:

```
feilan@feilan-kubuntu:/media/feilan/Data/devprojects/web/udemy-angular4/components101$ ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
node: 6.11.4
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.4
@angular/common: 4.4.4
@angular/compiler: 4.4.4
@angular/core: 4.4.4
@angular/forms: 4.4.4
@angular/http: 4.4.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.4
@angular/router: 4.4.4
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.4
@angular/language-service: 4.4.4
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Do a clean uninstall and reinstall:

1. Uninstall angular: **npm uninstall -g @angular/cli**
2. Check version (to make sure it is uninstalled): ng -v

   If it still shows the version, angular has not be uninstalled yet.

   If your cmd shows *'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.* it is uninstalled successfully
3. Reinstall using: **npm install -g @angular/cli**
4. Repeat step 2 to check the version and use ng new proj-name

Answer (score 0):

The fix can be found here see delasteve's answer
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues

Reinstall the CLI

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

Global package:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
# if npm version is > 5 then use `npm cache verify` to avoid errors (or to avoid using --force)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```